# what should i do so that messages from WhatsApp server to get delivered to appropriate recipient

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have send some messages to recipient while she had deactivated her WhatsApp account but now she's back still those single-ticked haven't been delivered. I just need help to deliver those messages because I want her to know I have been messaging all these days.

Comment: Just send her your screenshots ;)

Answer (score 0):

If she deactivated before 30 days the messages won't get delivered, because WhatsApp stores the message in the server for 30days. [Read it here, Even I haven't tested -> Scroll to update section](http://techwelkin.com/how-to-stop-a-whatsapps-message-sent-to-wrong-person) until it gets delivered.

If she activated within 30days probably with no DP or status she should have blocked you.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the messages and click on the forward option. Then select her contact and send it again.